# Make pdf builder page on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

It is possible to do in wordpress feature like this https://alanshortall.com/pdf ?
So people can select custom images from all posts and generate pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I did a very extensive search.
Mmas did not find any plugin based on your request ,.
I even saw some users who needed the same add-on style and the solution they found was to look for a developer. To create this plugin.

I hope you find!
Be sure to send feedback
good luck

Comment: Thanks for your help!